# How to get data from database on selecting item in dropdownlist MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC. I am working on "Index" View to display a list of records(items) bases on a dropdown of Categories. I want to show records from databse based on selection of dropdownlist value.
I have two Models:

- Items
- Categories

There is categoryID IN BOth models. In Categories Models its primary key and foreign key in Items. Dropdownlist should be bind to database.

This is what I have tried so far?

```
  //Item COntroller
      public ActionResult Index(int id=1) {
        // var items = db.Items.ToArray();

        var items = db.Items.Where(i => i.CategoryID == id).ToList();

        var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        ViewBag.Categories = categories;
        //  var content=db.Items.ToList();                
        return View(items);
    }


    //View (index)
      <script>

    $("#Categories").change(function (event) {
        var userId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Index","Item")",
            data: { id: userId },
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                //Whatever result you have got from your controller with 
              html partial view replace with a specific html.
                alert(data);
                $("#divView").html(data); // HTML DOM replace
            }
        });
    });

     </script>
     <h2>Index</h2>
       <div class="form-group">
    @*@Html.LabelFor("CategoryID",new SelectList(pr htmlAttributes: new { 
       @class 
    = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
   <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("Categories", new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, 
  "CategoryID", "CategoryName"), "--Please Select--", htmlAttributes: new { 
  @class = "form-control" })
    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, "", new { @class 
   = "text-danger" })*@
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </div>
   <div id="divView"></div>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" 
    src="/Item/RetrieveImage/@item.Id" />
    <div>
        <p>@item.ItemName</p>
        <p>Rs.<span>@item.Price</span><span class="pull-right">Order&nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox" name="cbOrder" id="@item.Id" /></span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  }
```

Comment: Ok, this is your attempt, good, but you forgot to tell us in what way it is deficient. What is going wrong / not working for you? There are lots of examples online (including previous SO questions) showing how to bind to dropdownlists in MVC, did you try anything?

Comment: Yes. I have tried but issue is In Index view I want to get list of records not a single one. there is @model IEnumerable<MvcHotel.Models.Items> in Index.

Comment: well you're doing ToList when you fetch it from the DB, and then passing that to the view, so what's the issue with that? Looks fine to me. But what relationship does that have to a dropdownlist? Your code doesn't even have a populated dropdownlist in it yet, it looks like you haven't even attempted to solve this yourself. Like I said, plenty of examples of dropdownlists online. Create the dropdownlist element, bind the category data to it, learn how to post that value back to the server, then learn how to restrict your other query based on that value, and then return the restricted results.

Answer (score -1):

as per my understanding you are using foreach loop to iterate the items list
but due to the if condition ( if (item.CategoryID == ViewBag.CategoryID))
the record is displayed only once where if condition is successful.
if you remove the if condition then all the records will get displayed.

and also check @Model.Count() of the model, might be you are getting only one object in the list

Comment: removing the `if` doesn't solve the OP's stated problem. They _want_ to restrict the results by category, they just haven't done any research in how to populate their dropdownlist or know how to use the selected value to influence the query.

Comment: I can get full records if I write: var content=db.Items.ToArray(); return View(content); but I want to show all records on selection of category. How i can do it Please show an example. I have stucked here

Comment: @WaqasQureshi As I already stated you can find dozens of examples of this kind of thing online already. If you tried something, show it. If not, go and research more.

Comment: @ADyson I have changed the code after researching over the internet. Now using this got I have display the records but they are of category 1 as i written in the parameters of "Index" Action "int id=1". So I want the code to work like I select some value then show me records

Comment: @WaqasQureshi your code is circular, you are trying to re-insert the whole of the Index view into a div which is already inside the index view. You need one Action method to return the whole index view at the start, and another which returns a _partial_ view of just the HTML for the items when requested by ajax.